# Infinite central series of a group

Tags: group-theory

Is there any definition for an infinite central series?

In this link only finite ones are acceptable:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group#Definition

Comment: I think you mean: "transfinite central series".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the upper and lower central series can be extended, and defined over arbitrary ordinals. The group is called *hypercentral* if the limit of its upper central series is the whole group, and *hypocentral* if the limit of its lower central series is the trivial subgroup.